# How to send multiple JSON results from controller to view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Here I am sending one item from controller to view. How can I send more than one item from controller to view??

```
  //Controller 

  public JsonResult GetQuantity(string id)
    {
       string getQuantity = "";
       string items="Hello Quantity"
       getQuantity = items.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
       return Json(getQuantity, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


        // View

      function GetQuantity(id) {


            var targetDiv = '#divYarnDistributionViewer';
            var url = "/STSM/STSA/YarnDistribution/GetQuantity/" + id;
            var form = $("#frmYarnDistributionViewer");

            var serializedForm = form.serialize();

            $.post(url, serializedForm, function (result) {
                $("#YarnDistribution_StockQuantity").val(result);

            }, "json");

        return false;


    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the help of  @JDupont And @Kevin Simple, I have solved my problem.
Thanks to these guys.

```
     public JsonResult GetQuantity(string id)
      {
         // Here id is not used, i will use it to get Quantity and unit for my project purpose.
        string getQuantity = "";  
        string getUnit = "";       
        string item1="Hello Quantity" 
        string item2="Hello Unit"
        getQuantity = item1.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        getUnit = item2.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return Json(new { getQuantity, getUnit },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }


    // View

  function GetQuantity(id) {
        var targetDiv = '#divYarnDistributionViewer';
        var url = "/STSM/STSA/YarnDistribution/GetQuantity/" + id;
        var form = $("#frmYarnDistributionViewer");
        var serializedForm = form.serialize();
        $.post(url, serializedForm, function (result) {
            $("#YarnDistribution_StockQuantity").val(result.getQuantity);
            $("#YarnDistribution_StockUnit").val(result.getUnit );

        }, "json");

      return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,just like this in your controller:

```
return Json(resulst = new {Quantity = 5, Price = 285,...}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In your Js,

var Quantity = result.Quantity;
var Price = result.Price;

Answer (score 1):

You can return an object with multiple properties as JSON.
Lets say you have a basic object with some properties:

```
public class Stock{
    public string Quantity { get; set; }

    public string Quantity1 { get; set; }
}
```

You can fetch some stock from wherever your data source is and map the quantity to your Stock object. For simplicity we will just create a hardcoded Stock object:

```
public JsonResult GetAllQuantities()
{
   Stock stock = new Stock() {
       Quantity = "2",
       Quantity1 = "3"
   };
   return Json(stock, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

To see how the Json is being sent to the client you can always print it to the console in the callback of your ajax request.
Be sure to change your request from post to get as you are simply fetching data.

Comment: how can i used stock in function GetQuantity? @JDupont

Comment: By referencing the model with a using at the top of your controller file along with the rest of your usings. Create the Stock object under Models.

Comment: I am not taking about list i am taking about multiple fields such as your class Stock has a property Quantity and suppose there is another property Quantity1. now i want to send these two fields into my function.And i retrieve this like      $("#YarnDistribution_quantity ").val(result1),      $("#YarnDistribution_quantity 1").val(result2) like that . is it possible

Comment: Yes. Both mine and Kevin's answer will allow you to do this. In your callback function you would say: $("#YarnDistribution_StockQuantity").val(result.Quantity); and $("#YarnDistribution_StockQuantity1").val(result.Quantity1);
The only difference is Kevin uses an anonymous object that may or may not suit your needs better.

Comment: Look at the edits to my original answer please. Let me know if it clears things up.